# Permissions for end users in Omnistudio

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript

We're currently working on a proof of concept (POC) to use Omnistudio in Lightning experience (without Experience Cloud), specifically Omniscripts. However, we're unsure about the necessary permissions and sharing settings for end users who will be utilizing Omniscript components.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_setup_omnistudio_user_permission_sets.htm&type=5), we need to create a new permission set called "OmniStudio Standard User" and assign it to end users. However, even after assigning this permission set, users are still unable to access the flows. We've found that changing the sharing settings of certain objects to "Public read-only" allows the flow to work. These objects include Omni Data Transformation Items, Omni Data Transformations, Omni Electronic Signature Templates, Omni Process Compilations, Omni Process Elements, Omni Processes, and Omni UI Cards.

Interestingly, even if we remove the permission set from users but keep the sharing settings of the above objects to "Read Only", the flow still works. We're curious to know how others have set up permissions in their org and whether assigning the newly created permission set to end users is necessary. Additionally, we'd appreciate any best practices for assigning permissions.

Comment: We had a similar issue where we assigned the correct permission sets and permission set licenses as per the documentation. The issue was resolved when we added the additional permissions of Public Read-Only on the org's sharing settings for all Objects with the word `Omnistudio` in it :-)